# How to use a for loop to iterate through a list of dictionaries, select a key, and append the values to a new list

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm a beginner and this is a basic question. I need to use a for loop to iterate through a list of dictionaries, and for a certain key in each of the dictionaries, append the value to a new list. The original list is a list of cities, with each dictionary in the list representing a city and containing information about the city. I need the loop to pick out the 'Population' key in each city dictionary, and append the value to a new list called city_populations.

I've only managed to append the population from one of the dictionaries to the list. Having trouble getting it to iterate through the list of dictionaries and append each population from each city. Here are three things I've tried:

Attempt 1:

```
city_populations = []
for city in cities:
    city_populations.append(cities[0]['Population'])
city_populations
```

Attempt 2:

```
city_populations = []
for city in cities:
    city_populations.append(cities[index]['Population'])
city_populations
```

Attempt 3:

```
city_populations = []
for city in cities:
    index = 0
    city_populations.append(cities[index]['Population'])
    index =+ 1
city_populations
```

Here is the list of cities:

```
[{'City': 'Buenos Aires',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 2891000,
  'Area': 4758},
 {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2800000, 'Area': 2731},
 {'City': 'Pyeongchang',
  'Country': 'South Korea',
  'Population': 2581000,
  'Area': 3194},
 {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200},
 {'City': 'Albuquerque',
  'Country': 'New Mexico',
  'Population': 559277,
  'Area': 491},
 {'City': 'Los Cabos',
  'Country': 'Mexico',
  'Population': 287651,
  'Area': 3750},
 {'City': 'Greenville', 'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 84554, 'Area': 68},
 {'City': 'Archipelago Sea',
  'Country': 'Finland',
  'Population': 60000,
  'Area': 8300},
 {'City': 'Walla Walla Valley',
  'Country': 'USA',
  'Population': 32237,
  'Area': 33},
 {'City': 'Salina Island', 'Country': 'Italy', 'Population': 4000, 'Area': 27},
 {'City': 'Solta', 'Country': 'Croatia', 'Population': 1700, 'Area': 59},
 {'City': 'Iguazu Falls',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 0,
  'Area': 672}]
```

How could I achieve what I am trying to do here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please select an answer if your question was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not actually using the different values in the dictionary as you iterate through it. Try this:

```
city_populations = []
for city in cities:
    city_populations.append(city['Population'])
city_populations
```

Your 3rd attempt is actually almost there. It would work if you just put `index = 0` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution plus some bonus code:

```
cities = [{'City': 'Buenos Aires',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 2891000,
  'Area': 4758},
 {'City': 'Toronto', 'Country': 'Canada', 'Population': 2800000, 'Area': 2731},
 {'City': 'Pyeongchang',
  'Country': 'South Korea',
  'Population': 2581000,
  'Area': 3194},
 {'City': 'Marakesh', 'Country': 'Morocco', 'Population': 928850, 'Area': 200},
 {'City': 'Albuquerque',
  'Country': 'New Mexico',
  'Population': 559277,
  'Area': 491},
 {'City': 'Los Cabos',
  'Country': 'Mexico',
  'Population': 287651,
  'Area': 3750},
 {'City': 'Greenville', 'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 84554, 'Area': 68},
 {'City': 'Archipelago Sea',
  'Country': 'Finland',
  'Population': 60000,
  'Area': 8300},
 {'City': 'Walla Walla Valley',
  'Country': 'USA',
  'Population': 32237,
  'Area': 33},
 {'City': 'Salina Island', 'Country': 'Italy', 'Population': 4000, 'Area': 27},
 {'City': 'Solta', 'Country': 'Croatia', 'Population': 1700, 'Area': 59},
 {'City': 'Iguazu Falls',
  'Country': 'Argentina',
  'Population': 0,
  'Area': 672}]

# This is the specific solution to your problem
city_populations = []
for city in cities:
    city_populations.append(city['Population'])
print(city_populations)

# In order to better understand what is happening please try also this code
for city in cities:
    print (city)
    print (city['Population'])

# A more pythonic and elegant way to solve the problem is using list comprehension
city_populations = [city["Population"] for city in cities]
print(city_populations)

# If you want to be able to access specific keys / values you can use items() 
for key, value in cities[0].items():
    print ("Key: " + key)
    print("Value: " + str(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop worrying about indexes. You want every `Population` field of each dictionary of the list of dictionaries.

Use a list comprehension:

```
city_populations = [city["Population"] for city in cities]
```